# How to disable cache in Joomla module custom

Tags: php, caching, joomla, module, joomla2.5

I have created a custom module in joomla. My website has the cache turned on. The problem is my module executes some functions but when cache is turned on, it doesn't work. How can I exclude my module from joomla chache?

The module is a form and its submit action is reloading the page, so when the page is reloaded the module executes again and my save is in the same module.LOL. I know is weird. Then can you  say me a way to submit form and save the data in db...?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the "advanced" fieldset for any core module. They all have cache management of one kind or another, some simple, some more complex.

Comment: Actually rereading your question ... you probably need to use com_ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

you can exclude the module from the Joomla cache using this [extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/cache/13155).

For standard method of submitting a form inside module is something like.

Any related component for this module then use that components `controller` and `model` for the purpose.

Normally form kind of thing should related with components otherwise this kind of coding may required.

Hope its helps..